# Change text colour depending on positive or negative integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this very simple calculator which I have written in JavaScript. Basically it works out the profit between two integers with the tax amount being 5%.

I would like the output (`#result`) to change colour depending if the result number is either a positive or negative integer.

Here is my calculator's HTML:

```html
Buying Price
<br /><br />
<input id="buying" type="text">
<br /><br />
Selling Price               
<br /><br />
<input id="selling" type="text">
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<p id="result" name="r1"></p>
```

Here is my calculator's JS:

```
function output(){
    var buying = document.getElementById('buying').value;
    var selling = document.getElementById('selling').value;

    parseInt(selling) / 20;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  parseInt(selling) - parseInt(buying) - parseInt(selling) / 20;
}
```

Here is a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac81ee78/

I have attempted using jQuery for this however it did not work.

Please if anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tip for the future: "it did not work" is a 100% useless statement, unless you also describe *how* you tried it and *what* happened instead. Fortunately, in this case, the fact that you tried (something involving) jQuery is completely irrelevant anyway, so it doesn't really matter that we have no idea what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified your code a bit so it changes color based on the sign of the output. jQuery isn't needed for this - we can use plain JS functions to change the color of the output box.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var resultEl = document.getElementById('result');

function output() {
    var buying = document.getElementById('buying').value;
    var selling = document.getElementById('selling').value;
    var resultVal = parseInt(selling) - parseInt(buying) - parseInt(selling) / 20;
    resultEl.innerHTML = resultVal
    if (resultVal >= 0) {
        resultEl.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        resultEl.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
Buying Price
<br />
<br />
<input id="buying" type="text">
<br />
<br />Selling Price
<br />
<br />
<input id="selling" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<p id="result" name="r1"></p>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/ac81ee78/2/

Comment: I know the OP used `parseInt()`, but I suspect that's actually a bug. At least, if the code is *supposed* to only accept integer inputs, there should be some indication that if the user types in "9.99" it'll be truncated to "9".

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this based on the result value with help of ternary operator

```js
function output() {
  var buying = document.getElementById('buying').value,
    selling = document.getElementById('selling').value,
    res = document.getElementById('result'),
    result = parseInt(selling) - parseInt(buying) - parseInt(selling) / 20;;
  res.innerHTML = result;
  res.style.color = result >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
}
```

```html
Buying Price
<br />
<br />
<input id="buying" type="text">
<br />
<br />Selling Price
<br />
<br />
<input id="selling" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<p id="result" name="r1"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery` example (takes decimals as well)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on('click', function() {
    var buying = parseFloat($('#buying').val());
    var selling = parseFloat($('#selling').val());
    var result = (selling - buying - (selling/20)).toFixed(2);
    $('#result').html(result);
    if (result < 0) {
      $('#result').css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
      $('#result').css('color', 'green');
    }        
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Buying Price
<br /><br />
<input id="buying" type="text"/>
<br /><br />
Selling Price    
<br /><br />
<input id="selling" type="text"/>
<br /><br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" />
<p id="result" name="r1"></p>
```